# My jquery ajax call is not working when I call web services which retrieves data from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I am new working with jquery ajax calls in fact my first time and, I am running into a issue here my web service is working but for some reason when I try to call it from jquery ajax the data is not retrieve.

Please I've been working the whole day on this and I need to finish it tonight.

My web method is this :

```
public Didyoumean SayHello(string search)
    {
        Didyoumean Didyoumean = new Didyoumean();
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("USP_DidYouMean",con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@search",search);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                Didyoumean.SearchInput = reader["detail"].ToString();
            }
            reader.Close();
            con.Close();

        }
        return Didyoumean;

    }
```

my Didyoumean class is this:

```
public class Didyoumean
{
    public string SearchInput { get; set; }
}
```

my ajax call is this (the error is most likely to be here)

function bla() {

```
var SearchInput = document.getElementById("#locationSearchInput").value;

var DataObject = { search: SearchInput };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/kiosk/EmailCoupon.asmx/SayHello",
    data: JSON.stringify({dataObject}), 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function (data) {
        $('.tags_select a').html(data.d); 
    },
    error: function () {
        $('.tags_select a').html("<p>no suggestion</p>")
    }
});
```

}

and finally my html

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="bla()"/>
<div class="tags_select">
    <a href="#"></a>
```

Basically what I am trying to do is depending on the data in my database the application give suggestions for spelling errors.

note: do not pay attention to the name of the functions and methods this is just a test.

Comment: What exactly not working? Are you receiving errors? What happens when you debug?

Comment: Did you put a WebMethod attribute in your method?

Comment: Does your .asmx class have the [ScriptServiceAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: yes, it does have the attribute, the web services is actually working (I tested it)  the problem is on the ajax call, it does not retrieve the data from the webmethod when the parameter is inserted.

Comment: Is the curly bracket in JSON.stringify() a typo?

Comment: @AlexMontano Check your browser console to see what is actually happening ?

Comment: Mr @AlexMontano I will recommend you to paste all code including referenced files

Comment: thank you guys I already solved the issue, it was something stupid

Comment: var Object = $('#locationSearchInput').val(); was the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your service might be like this

```
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public Didyoumean SayHello(string search)
        {
            Didyoumean didyoumean = new Didyoumean();
            didyoumean.searchInput = "result of " + search;
            return didyoumean;
        }
    }
```

and your javascript is

```
    function test() {
    var SearchInput = "test";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/WebService1.asmx/SayHello",
         data: JSON.stringify({search:SearchInput}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var didYouMean = data.d;
            alert(didYouMean.searchInput);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);

        }
    });
}
```